# Creating Packages With Perl

Tags: perl, module, package, perl-module

I seem to be having a lot of trouble with making my first, simple Package (actually it is my first package period). I am doing everything I should be doing (I think) and it still isn't working. Here is the Package (I guess you can call it a Module):

```
package MyModule;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);

$VERSION     = 1.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = ();
@EXPORT_OK   = qw(func1 func2);
%EXPORT_TAGS = ( DEFAULT => [qw(&func1)],
             Both    => [qw(&func1 &func2)]);

sub func1  { return reverse @_  }
sub func2  { return map{ uc }@_ }

1;
```

I saved this module as MyModule (yes, it was saved as a .pm file) in `Perl/site/lib` (this is where all of my modules that are not built-in are stored). Then I tried using this module inn a Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw (J u s t ~ A n o t h e r ~ P e r l ~ H a c k e r !);

use Mine::MyModule qw(&func1 &func2);
print func1(@list),"\n";
print func2(@list),"\n";
```

I save this as `my.pl`. Then I run `my.pl` and get this error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::func1 called at C:\myperl\examplefolder\my.pl line 7.
```

Can someone please explain why this happens? Thanks in advance!

***Note***:*Yes my examples were from [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/). See [the Perl Monks "Simple Module Tutorial"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=102347). Thank You [tachyon](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=80749)!*

Comment: Rolled back because question wasn't making sense with the `Mine::MyModule` changed to `MyModule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your package name and your use name don't match.  If you have your module in a folder called `Mine` then you need to name your package accordingly:

`package Mine::MyModule`

If you don't have it in that folder then you need to remove that from your `use` call

`use MyModule`

Comment: WOW! Now I fell stupid. Thanks. By the way, it was in the Mine directory before it was edited.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
package Mine::MyModule;
```

And it should be in the Mine directory under Perl/site/lib.